# Erro npm install angularjs-dragula

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Preciso instalar o

angularjs-dragula
ng2-dragula
react-dragula

Num primeiro momento tive o erro:

```
C:\Users\email\Desktop\Parafernalia Test> npm install angular js-dragula --save
  npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\User\email\package.jason'
  npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
  npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\email\package.json'
  npm WARN email No description
  npm WARN email No repository field.
  npm WARN email No README data
  npm WARN email No license field.
```

+angularjs-dragula@2.0.0
added 7 packages from 3 contributors and audited 8 packages in 24.066s

Criei o arquivo na pasta do projeto
    - package.json

Passei novamente o comando e o erro agora é:

```
C:\Users\email\Desktop\Parafernalia Teste>npm install angularjs-dragula --save
  npm ERR! file C:\Users\email\Desktop\Parafernalia Test\package.json
  npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
  npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
  npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
  npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
  npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
  npm ERR!     C:\Users\email\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-05T13_59_46_328Z-debug.log
```

Esse mesmo erro ocorre quando eu tento o comando para instalar react-dragula

Minha file package.json está vazia.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

PS.: Dragula é uma biblioteca js para DnD
https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: Por favor, adicione o seu `package.json` à pergunta, e substitua as imagens pelo erro em formato de texto.

Comment: Troquei as imagens por formato texto. e minha file package.json não tem nenhum conteúdo ainda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque os arquivos `.json` foram criados manualmente, sem uma [estrutura válida](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

Quando o comando `npm install angularjs-dragula --save` é executado, ocorre o [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) do conteúdo do arquivo `package.json`, porém como está vazio o seguinte erro é retornado:

> npm ERR! JSON.parse Falied to parse json

Repare que umas das linhas diz o seguinte:

> npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON

Ou seja, o conteúdo do `package.json` deveria ser um json válido.

Uma vez que o argumento `--save` é utilizado, a dependência é salva no  `package.json`, no nó `dependencies`:

```
//...
"dependencies": {
    "angularjs-dragula": "^2.0.0"
}
//...
```

Como o arquivo `package.json` foi criado sem conteúdo e o parse falhou, o `npm` não consegue salvar a dependência.

## Como resolver o problema?

Como o arquivo `package.json` está em branco, basta apagá-lo e executar o comando no terminal dentro da pasta do projeto. O comando irá criar o arquivo `package.json` automaticamente:

```
npm init
```

Depois de responder algumas perguntas no terminal, repare que agora o `package.json` foi gerado com uma estrutura inicial contendo um json válido, entretanto o nó "dependencies" não existe, uma vez que não foi adicionado qualquer dependência ao projeto.

Para adicionar a dependência, execute o comando:

```
npm install angularjs-dragula --save
```

Repare que agora o nó existe e a dependência foi adicionada com sucesso ao projeto.